# Display (flat) row of data from a table in a specific format using MVC / LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a table that has column names similar to "ADDRESS", "OLD_ADDRESS", "CITY", "OLD_CITY", "STATE", "OLD_STATE"..... and so on. I'm pulling this information using entity framework query and passing the model into an ASP.NET MVC view.

I need to display this information  in a tabular format that looks something like this

[image]

I need to compare the old and the new fields and if there is a difference in the values,  display it. 
What is the best way to do something like this?
I could build this the normal way by looping through the model and comparing if (item.ADDRESS   == item.OLD_ADDRESS) { .... }, but this particular table has about 100 columns and I would essentially be writing 50 "if" conditions. Assume that only one row is returned from the linq query.

I'm reading this information from a legacy database and cannot redesign it. 
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

-----------------------------EDIT 1----------------------------
Here's what I've tried so far -

```
@foreach (var BusRels in Model)
           {               
               foreach (var busrel in BusRels.GetType().GetProperties())
               {   
                    if (busrel.Name.IndexOf("OLD") > -1) {                        
                            {
                                var fieldVal = busrel.GetValue(BusRels, null);                                
                                if ( fieldVal != null)
                                {
                                    if (!fieldVal.ToString().Trim().IsEmpty())
                                    {   
                                        <tr>
                                        @{
                                            //BusRels.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == fieldVal.
                                        var displayName = busrel.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute), false)
                                        .Cast<System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute>()
                                        .FirstOrDefault().DisplayName;
                                        }

                                        <td>@displayName</td>
                                        <td>@busrel.GetValue(BusRels, null)</td>
                                        <td>???????</td>
                                        </tr>   
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
               }
```

I guess the problem here is that I can't seem to get the 'new" value to display next to the old value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ to get the values that you want to display:

```
var matches = from BusRels in Model
              from busrel in BusRels.GetType().GetProperties()
              where busrel.Name.StartsWith("OLD")
              let fieldVal = busrel.GetValue(BusRels, null)
              where Convert.ToString(fieldVal).IsNullOrWhiteSpace()
              let newval = BusRels.GetType()
                                  .GetProperty(busrel.Name.Replace("OLD_", ""))
                                  .GetValue(BusRels, null)
              where newval.ToString().Trim() != fieldVal.ToString().Trim()
              let displayName = busrel.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute), false)
                                      .Cast<System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute>()
                                      .FirstOrDefault().DisplayName
              select new
                     {
                         DisplayName = displayName,
                         NewVal = newval,
                         OldVal = fieldVal
                     };
```

Then you just have to loop through and display them.

Answer (score 0):

OK...a bit messy but looks like it's working.
if anyone reading this has a better approach, I'd like to hear it. thanks.

```
@foreach (var BusRels in Model)
                    {
                        foreach (var busrel in BusRels.GetType().GetProperties())
                        {
                            if (busrel.Name.IndexOf("OLD") > -1)
                            {
                                {
                                    var fieldVal = busrel.GetValue(BusRels, null);
                                    if (fieldVal != null)
                                    {
                                        if (!fieldVal.ToString().Trim().IsEmpty())
                                        {   
                                            var newval = BusRels.GetType().GetProperty(busrel.Name.Replace("OLD_", "")).GetValue(BusRels, null);

                                            //BusRels.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == fieldVal.
                                            var displayName = busrel.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute), false)
                                            .Cast<System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute>()
                                            .FirstOrDefault().DisplayName;
                                            var oldval = busrel.GetValue(BusRels, null);


                                            if (newval.ToString().Trim() != oldval.ToString().Trim())
                                            {  
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>@displayName</td>
                                                <td>@newval</td>
                                                <td>@oldval</td>
                                            </tr>   
                                            }
}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```